# Smoothness of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, smooth-manifolds, taylor-expansion

I'm reading lecture about taylor expansion but i wonder in following example why  he took  $x\longmapsto \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ as function in $]-\infty,1[$ of class $\mathcal{C}^{n+1}$ and not in $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$ of class $\mathcal{C}^{n+1}$

[image]

reference
[image]

since the author is looking at the limit when $x\to 0$ and a neighbourhood near $0$ so can we take the neighbourhood of $0$ which is $]-\epsilon,+\epsilon[$

or  then statements about the real numbers below 1 is just question of choice by the author

Comment: If the proof is looking at the limit when $x \to 0$ and a neighbourhood near $0$, then statements about the real numbers below $1$ are sufficient without having to think about the discontinuity at $1$

Comment: so it's suffice to take  neighbourhood of $0$ which is $]-\epsilon,+\epsilon [$